# Setting attribute values dynamically

Tags: android, view, attributes, dynamic

There are always a few attribute values that Android doesn't explicitly define how to change and set dynamically for views. In my case, I'm trying to set the `ListView`'s vertical scroll bar drawable. There's no method in the `ListView` class that lets you set this. I can only define this in the XML using `android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/new_scroll_bar"`. Is there ANY workaround that would let me change attributes not otherwise defined dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems impossible, since the document doesn't refer to a corresponding method to set that XML attribute.

Answer (score 0):

In the docs it says it corresponds to the global resource attribute:

```
android.R.attr.scrollbarThumbHorizontal
```

You can set this equal to a drawable programatically.

Ref: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:scrollbarThumbVertical

Let me know if that is what you were trying to get to.

Comment: Yes this is what I'm talking about, but how can I set this value programaically? What method to I call on `ListView` to set this? There's no such method as `ListView.setScrollBarThumbVertical()`. Can you help me find what the specific methods I'm suppose to use to set this?